# What's going on with Add to Source Control in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I had no source control set up for my solution.

But when I right clicked it and chose 'Add to Source Control', it spewed out the following output, which *seems* to be setting it all up and creating it automatically in the projects own folder.

```
A new Git repository has been created for you in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Sites\MySolution.
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Sites\MySolution
An existing Git repository was found in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Sites\MySolution.
Commit d59ef659 created locally in repository C:\Users\Me\Documents\Sites\MySolution
```

This seems like magic to me. I've dabbled in version control but have never used it seriously as most of my projects are personal and maintained by me alone. Has this option always been available?

Comment: As Visual Studio was around long before git existed, that option has not always been available. :-)

Comment: coulda used SVN... but apparently VS was around even before that!

Comment: Yep, it was around before that too. :-)